# The application does not start on the emulator

Tags: android, react-native

I use this [starter](https://github.com/ueno-llc/react-native-starter)

I run

```
react-native start
```

Then

```
react-native run-android
```

I see an error in the emulator (Android studio SDK 28 android 9)
[image]

I tried and it did not help

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Comment: try creating an app with  ````"react-native init appName"````

Comment: try running this command  ````"android-dev": "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 && react-native run-android"````

Comment: react-native init appName - it work, but i want use starter )